# Printing to HP printer results in errors

Tags: windows-8, printing, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 400 printer, connected to the network. There are three clients printing to it - a Mac OS X Yosemite laptop, a Windows 8.1 64 bit laptop and a Windows 8.1 64 bit desktop.

A few days ago, the Windows desktop lost it. Printing anything results in 'PCL XL Error' messages. I spent some time with HP support, we uninstalled everything and installed it again (the entire HP software suite), but the problem persisted. I installed the universal PCL 5, PCL 6 and Postscript drivers - none of them works properly. PCL 6 and Postscript report errors, while PCL 5 prints garbled documents.

All the same while, the Windows laptop and OS X laptop print fine. Printing internal pages (the configuration, for example) and receiving faxes is also fine. So the problem is obviously with the desktop.

It seems as if there is some sort of communications error between the desktop and printer. It can't be a problem on the printer side, because it works with other computers. So it has to be on the desktop side. However, everything else works well - I don't see any network errors when accessing any other service.

I'm quite lost there. I really don't want to reinstall the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the AVG antivirus. I don't know how and why. Disabling it fixed the issue. So now I'm using another antivirus program.